# How can I edit notes in presenters view for PowerPoint 2016?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, microsoft-powerpoint, editing

I am using Microsoft Office PowerPoint 2016 on Windows 10 x64 to present using presenters view.

While presenting I want to edit/copy/paste into the notes section of the presenters view.

How do I achieve the above?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't think it's possible to actually edit your slide notes while you are giving the PowerPoint presentation, but hopefully someone else knows of a method that I haven't heard before.

Comment: @Run5k Are you aware of other presentation software that would have this feature.

Comment: The only other office suite I ever recommend is [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), and I don't think the [Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) application has that capability, either.  What you are asking for could prove to be rather challenging, because typically you would prepare your notes in advance, save the file after you fine-tune the presentation, and then initiate the slide show.  By then, the time for editing and updating is over so that capability wouldn't be available.

Comment: @Run5k Here's my use case. I want students to 1. download software online or 2. follow a blog post outlining the steps for problem resolution and both these cases have a urlhave that is obnoxiously long and should not be on the slide. I want to open my browser and follow along with them to help them understand because the process is complicated. How do I achieve it? I have the urls in my notes I want to copy the url and paste it in the browser. 

Additionally I want to edit/update content on my notes which have several other use cases that space constraints would not allow me to type. Thanks

Comment: You may have to compromise. If long URLs are the biggest challenge, you can potentially use either [TinyURL](https://tinyurl.com/) or [Bitly](https://bitly.com/) to shorten them to something much more slide-friendly. However, if you *still* want to edit/update your notes, you could potentially open PowerPoint in the **Normal** view and adjust the zoom to make the slide bigger... hopefully large enough for the students to easily see, while allowing you to access your notes for each one.

Comment: @Run5k **Normal** view... remember I'm presenting using the _Presenters_ view . I do not know or understand how to combine both of them.

I am not sure of the process you are trying to explain either.

Comment: The bottom line is that you can't edit/update your notes in *Presenters* view.  You would need to either use a different view, or concede that you can't edit/update your notes.  If I were you, I would shorten the long URLs using one of the methods I mentioned before, and then if I still had *"several other use cases that space constraints would not allow me to type"*, create a folder hierarchy within my web browser's bookmarks that made them easily accessible.

Comment: I think you could accomplish this with a bit of VBA that launches a form; on the form there would be a text box populated with the text from the current slide's notes. You could edit the text there, then press a button that would replace the slide's notes with the text from the text box.  An invisible button on each slide could have a Run Macro action setting to launch the form for editing.